# How to display list elements from inside a loop 1 by 1

Tags: python

I have 2 lists in my code:

```
list1 = ['Math', 'Science ', 'English']
list2 = ['10', '11 ', '12']
```

and this is what I've tried to code so far:

```
for text_files in list1:
    i = 0
    while i < len(list1):
        print(list1[i])
        print(list2[i])
        i += 1
```

This is what my output is supposed to look like, but my output is becoming too many:

```
Math 
10
Science 
11
English 
12
```

Comment: The `print` function has an optional `end` parameter. You could use it. You don't need to accept the default newline character if you don't want. You could also directly iterate over `zip(list1,list2)` rather than using indices, though that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers have pointed out: You don't need the first `for` loop here. I agree with the method suggested in the comments: Using `zip` instead of accessing elements by their index.

Here are three different ways to print your desired output, starting with the most sensible / readable:

```
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

---

```
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    print(a, b, sep="\n")
```

---

```
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    print(f"{a}\n{b}")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could print them on the same line to avoid the console getting spammed.

```
for text_files in list1:
i = 0
while i < len(list1):
    print(list1[i], list2[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect, this code will not execute. It also doesn't solve OP's problem, as it still includes the unnecessary `for` loop.